# Angular lazy loaded module failed to navigate to child routes

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading

I'm creating a dashboard app and so far I have two lazy loaded modules
`AuthModule` and `AdminModule`
My `app-routing-module.ts` looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
     path: '',
     loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
    },
    {
     path: 'admin',
     loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
     canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

My `app.component.html` has a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that should render the above routes inside it.

so these urls are working `/auth/` and `/admin/` perfectly

In my `admin-routing.module.ts` I have the following routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
      {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },
      {path: 'booking', component: BookingComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

so that `/admin/` route directly navigates to `/admin/dashboard/` which is also working perfectly.

In my `admin.component.html` I added another `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` that should renders `AdminModule` routes inside it, so I can have a sidenav bar layout.

The problem is that only the default route for `AdminModule` which is `/admin/dashboard` renders perfectly inside the second `router-outlet` whenever I try to navigate to any other child route like `/admin/users/` or `/admin/booking/` the app redirects to `NotFoundComponent`

Here's my problem illustrated.
[image: default child route for the admin module 'dashboard']
[image: trying to hit another child route]

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out the solution.

In your app.module file change the code to look like this:

```
   const routes: Routes = [
        {
         path: '',
         component: AuthComponent, //<--- Add this
         loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
        },
        {
         path: 'admin',
         component: AdminComponent, //<--- Add this
         loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
         canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
        },
        {
          path: '**',
          component: NotFoundComponent
        }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    }

)
```

In your lazy-loaded module routing file (`admin-routing.module.ts`) change the code to look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [

      {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
      {path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
      {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },
      {path: 'booking', component: BookingComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Now your code should work as expected

Comment: Doesn't this break the 'lazyness' -- by referencing `AdminComponent` in the root router, you must import `AdminModule` in your `AppModule`, therefore bundling it into the `main.js`?

Comment: @Charly No it does not. The admin module is it to be imported into the app module. Only import the Admin component. The admin component is part of the AppModule. But is children are lazy loaded.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
{
  path: '',
  component: AdminComponent,
  children: [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard'},
    {
      path: 'dashboard', 
      component: DashboardComponent,
      children: [
        {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent },
        {path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },
        {path: 'booking', component: BookingComponent }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you define `admin-routing.module.ts` means that all child routes expect an  element inside the AdminComponent's template. Angular will try to render all children into the AdminComponent.

I had the same problem. I didn't manage to render the child routes of a lazy loaded module inside the root router-outlet. I solved this issue by the following algorithm:

For each child Component `c` of a lazy loaded module `M` that should be rendered in the `AppComponent`'s outlet:

- create a lazy loaded module for `c`
- define a route in your app-routing.module under root with the path needed that points to the lazy loaded module `c`
- remove the route from `M`'s routing declaration

For `admin/users` this could look something like this:

`app-routing-module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
     path: '',
     loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
    },
    {
     path: 'admin',
     loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule',
     canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
    },
    {
     path: 'admin/users',
     loadChildren: './admin/users/admin-users.module#AdminUsersModule',
     canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
    },
    {
      path: '**',
      component: NotFoundComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

This solution has a couple of drawbacks:

1. you cannot encapsulate your modules as expected, i.e. the parent-child semantics gets lost
2. you cannot simply reuse deserialized modules from parent routes - in case you have deep nesting

So it's not ideal, but it works.